# Extracting a zip file to dynamic destination folder in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip

Well,I am using Rails 2.02 and ruby 1.8.6 in my application,I need to provide a feature to extract the zip file into dynamic destination folders.i.e Destination folder name is fixed based on that it has to search on PC for that folder and extract zip file into that PC.

For example,

In PC1 the destination folder path is `C:/sites/myfolder`

In PC2 the destination folder path is `D:/demo/for/myfolder`

In PC3 the destination folder path is `C:/myfolder`

In PC4 the destination folder path is `F:/path/to/myfolder`

Here,In this example my destination folder is myfolder,so in the above four cases the path is different for that.What I need was my rails application should search for the folder in pc and extract zip file into that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I hope running 1.8.6 isn't your idea. It's enormously out of date.

Comment: Its ok,If it is possible in 1.9.+ I can backport it.

Comment: You'll have to test if [rubyzip](https://github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip) works in such an old version of Ruby.

Comment: ZIP,FILE,FILEUTILS all are working fine,I am using that all.

Comment: Do you want to do this "feature" for the clients? Or you want to make this zipping on the server where your app is, and search/store the files there?

Comment: The `rubyzip` gem does a lot of `.zip` file manipulation for you, so it can expand, compact, whatever you want. If you can confirm it works in 1.8.6, that is.

Comment: yes,I want this feature for the clients.If pure ruby script is possible,then it is too good yaar.@ burninggramma

Comment: yes.In rubyzip many option is there but finding the right path is the problem.If we find the path by ruby script then we do extract there.@ tadman